# Iterate through data in *any* GAE entity?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to learn/use GAE ndb, and am struggling with something which *should* be simple.

Suppose I have a couple of types of entity:

```
class Cat(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    vicious = ndb.BooleanProperty(required = True)

class Dog(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    willfetch = ndb.BooleanProperty(required = True)
    canswim = ndb.BooleanProperty(required = True)
```

What I'm trying to do is find an easy way to interate through all of the data stored in **any** entity, with a single function, irrespective of the name of the entity, or the name or number of properties within the entity.

---

I have two problems; doing this:

```
f = "<<Entity name>>"
qry = f.query()
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'b'
```

This prevents me from programmatically accessing the entities (e.g. from a list of names).

---

Then, even if I refer to the Entity by name to fix this error, I can't iterate fully through what's returned:

```
qry = Cat.query()

for item in qry:
    for property in item:
        **display data**
```

...gives an error:

```
TypeError: '<<name>>' object is not iterable
```

Any thoughts?  I've not found anything in the GAE docs or elsewhere on here.

Comment: The first snippet couldn't give that error; `f` is a string, not a module, and you haven't referenced `b` anywhere. Please give your actual code, and the full traceback.

Comment: Supported ways to get kinds and properties of kinds are documented are functions of the metadata module. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata   see get_kinds() and get_properties_of_kind()

Comment: @Daniel, you're right - I apologise.  I was pasting from the interactive console incorrectly.  It should have been `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query'`.

Answer (score 1):

`ndb.Model._kind_map['ModelName']` will return the class for an kind-name (this is normally a string the same as the model's class).
Given an entity class, `Entity._properties` will return a list of it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
    from importlib import import_module

    module = import_module('api.models.datastore') # Your model module
    model = getattr(module, '<<Entity name>>')
    results = model.all() # or query()
    for result in results:
        members = inspect.getmembers(result, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
        members = [m for m in members if not m[0].startswith('_')]
        print # space for demo purposes
        for key, value in members:
            print "{} - {}".format(key, value) # or whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisC73, I couldn’t get your code working, but by borrowing some bits, came up with this, which does work, although it seems horribly difficult (and computationally heavy) to do something that *should* be a lot easier.

```
# the names of each property in the Cat entity, *in desired display order*
Cat_property_titles = ['name', 'age', 'vicious']

qry = Cat.query()

for entry in qry:
   members = inspect.getmembers(entry, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
   members = [m for m in members if not m[0].startswith('_')]
   for title in Cat_property_titles:
      for item in members:
         if item[0] == title:
            <<output item[0]>>
```

---

.

---

FWIW, you can return the names of the entity's properties easily:

```
qry = Cat.query()
props = Cat._properties   # returns a dictionary
```

...**but** it returns them in alphabetical order, meaning you can't (seem to) rely on the returned order of properties as your display order.

Comment: There's no need to do any of this. Both yours and Chris's solutions are unnecessarily complicated; Greg has shown you exactly what you can do with the functionality already available.

Comment: @Daniel, I don't agree.  Greg's advice is very useful for two purposes: 1) referring to an(y) entity class programmatically, and 2) returning the property titles for an entity.  However, it doesn't solve the problem of not being able to iterate through each result returned by a query in the manner I originally demonstrated wanting/needing to.  Happy to be proven wrong, though!